# cv2 does not show up in pip list in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, linux, opencv, ubuntu

CV2 is installed using pip and I can import it and use it. yet when I run pip list
in terminal, it does not show up (and nothing apparently related to it - eg: OpenCv - shows up).

Why is that?

I'm using Python3.

Comment: I just installed it a couple of days ago in Python 3.8 on Windows.  I had to use an unofficial distribution, but it shows up for me as `opencv-python`.  Perhaps you didn't install your with pip?